# UnboundID : How to encapsulate processBindRequest return value?

Tags: java, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm building an LDAP interface for my database. When a client request bind(), it will search in the database and check if it is valid or not.

```
public class Main {
    LDAPListener listener ;
    Main() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        int port = main.StartServer();

        try {
        LDAPConnection cn = new LDAPConnection("localhost",port);
            System.out.println("."+cn.isConnected()+" "+cn.getConnectedPort());
            cn.bind("uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com", "pass");
            cn.close();
            main.StopServer();
        } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            main.StopServer();}
    }

    public int StartServer() {
        int listenPort = 0;
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        LDAPListenerConfig config = new LDAPListenerConfig(listenPort, requestHandler);
        listener = new LDAPListener(config);

        try {
            listener.startListening();
            System.out.println(">port "+listener.getListenPort());          
        } catch (Exception e){System.out.println("e1> "+e.getMessage());}
        return listener.getListenPort();
    }

    public void StopServer(){
        System.out.println(">shutdown");
        listener.shutDown(true);
    }
}
```

Then, i modify LDAPListenerRequestHandler to communicate with the database, get the record as return value:

```
class RequestHandler extends LDAPListenerRequestHandler {
    @Override
    public LDAPMessage processBindRequest(int arg0, BindRequestProtocolOp arg1,
        List<Control> arg2) {
        String uid = arg1.getBindDN();
        String pass = arg1.getSimplePassword();
        System.out.println(">bind: "+ uid);
        // Database query: SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='uid' AND password='pass'
        // Get the record as return value
        return null;
    }
}
```

When i run it, i got error message from the bind line:

```
LDAPException(resultCode=80 (other), errorMessage='An unexpected exception was thrown while attempting to process the requested operation:  NullPointerException(trace='run(LDAPListenerClientConnection.java:461)', revision=15579)', diagnosticMessage='An unexpected exception was thrown while attempting to process the requested operation:  NullPointerException(trace='run(LDAPListenerClientConnection.java:461)', revision=15579)')
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1881)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1799)
```

I think, it is caused by processBindRequest() that return null. How to encapsulate my database record as LDAPMessage in that process?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the processBindRequest method must return a non-null response.

If the bind is successful (the user exists, is allowed to authenticate, and has provided the correct credentials) then you can create a successful response with code like:

```
 @Override()
 public LDAPMessage processBindRequest(final int messageID,
                                       final BindRequestProtocolOp request,
                                       final List<Control> controls)
 {
   return new LDAPMessage(messageID, 
        new BindResponseProtocolOp(ResultCode.SUCCESS_INT_VALUE, 
             null,  // No matched DN is needed
             null,  // No diagnostic message is needed
             null,  // No referral URLs are needed
             null), // No server SASL credentials are needed
        Collections.<Control>emptyList()); // Add empty list to return
 }
```

If the authentication is not successful, then you should probably return a response with a result code of INVALID_CREDENTIALS rather than SUCCESS, and if you want to provide a message to the client with information about why the bind failed, you can put that in the diagnostic message element.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
after edited processBindRequest() i still get the same error ResultCode=80

Comment: I would recommend that you enable debug logging (as described in the com.unboundid.util.Debug class) and see where and what exception is being thrown.  Since you haven't provided the full code you're using, it's hard to know what the specific problem is.